# Spark structured streaming - update data frame's schema on the fly

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, schema, spark-structured-streaming

I have a simple structured streaming job which monitors a directory for CSV files and writes parquet files - no transformation in between.

The job starts by building a data frame from reading CSV files using `readStream()`, with a schema which I get from calling a function called `buildSchema()`. Here is the code:

```scala
  var df = spark
    .readStream
    .option("sep", "|")
    .option("header","true")
    .schema(buildSchema(spark, table_name).get) // buildSchema() gets schema for me
    .csv(input_base_dir + table_name + "*")

  logger.info(" new batch indicator")

  if (df.schema != buildSchema(spark, table_name).get) {
    df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.collectAsList(), buildSchema(spark, table_name).get)
  }

  val query =
    df.writeStream
      .format("parquet")
      .queryName("convertCSVtoPqrquet for table " + table_name)
      .option("path", output_base_dir + table_name + "/")
      .trigger(ProcessingTime(60.seconds))
      .start()
```

The job runs fine, but my question is, I'd like to always use the latest schema to build my data frame, or in other words, to read from the CSV files. While `buildSchema()` can get me the latest schema, I'm not sure how to call it periodically (or once per CSV file), and then use the latest schema to somehow re-generate or modify the data frame.

When testing, my observation is that only the `query` object is running continuously batch after batch; the log statement that I put, and the `if()`statement for schema comparison, only happened once at the beginning of the application.

Can data frame schema in structured streaming job be modified after `query.start()` is called? What would you suggest as a good workaround if we cannot change the schema of a data frame?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are flexible in the input side, you should look into avro, avro schema registry and kafka streams

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `foreachBatch` method to load the latest schema periodically, then compare it to the concrete micro batch dataframe schema.
Example:

```
    var streamingDF = spark
      .readStream
      .option("sep", "|")
      .option("header", "true")
      .schema(buildSchema(spark, table_name).get) // buildSchema() gets schema for me
      .csv(input_base_dir + table_name + "*")


    val query =
      streamingDF
        .writeStream
        .foreachBatch((ds, i) => {
          logger.info(s"New batch indicator(${i})")
          val batchDf =
          if (ds.schema != buildSchema(spark, table_name).get) {
            spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(ds.collectAsList(), buildSchema(spark, table_name).get)
          } else {
            ds
          }
          batchDf.write.parquet(output_base_dir + table_name + "/")
        })
        .trigger(ProcessingTime(60.seconds))
        .start()
```